What movie were they watching at the drive-in in the movie Christine (1983)?
Arnie and his new girlfriend, Leigh, go to the drive-in. I can't tell what movie they are watching. I even listened to John Carpenter and Keith Gordon's (Arnie) commentary. They mention the movie and both say they forgot what it was.

I am curious because the choice of flick may, like most things in a movie, be intentional to let you understand some other facet, like the psychology of the protagonist.

This movie is Thank God It's Friday.

Thank God It's Friday tells several intertwining stories of the patrons and staff of the fictional Los Angeles disco nightclub The Zoo over the course of a single Friday evening.

From fast-rewind,

The movie playing on-screen at the drive-in is the Oscar-winning disco favorite "Thank God It's Friday".

Check out this YouTube video. The actor appeared to be the same in the above pic. And he is DeWayne Jessie




Can you also elaborate on the second part of the question if the choice of this film adds anything to the themes or characterization of Christine?

Though, OP is not asking for the second part, but I haven't seen those movies and if I'd have known, I definitely add this.

Maybe it was Disco that made the car evil. I'd buy that.
